# How to call a Swift asynchronous method with closure from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

My Swift implementation of the asynchronous method is as below:

```
import Foundation
import AlamofireObjectMapper
import Alamofire


@objc class ServerManager : NSObject {

    @objc static let sharedInstance = ServerManager()

    override init() {
    }
    func getList(lat:Double, lon:Double,handler: @escaping (Lists?,Error?)->Void) {

            Alamofire.request(ServerRequestRouter.getDataList(lat, long))
                .responseArray(keyPath:"searchList") {(response:DataResponse<Lists>) in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success:
                        if let data = response.result.value  {
                            handler(data, nil)
                        }
                    case .failure(let error):
                        handler(nil,error)
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Of course this works fine in Swift, however now I want to call it from Objective-C class, so my question is how to change it so that it can be called from Objective-C?

What I have tried?

```
 @objc  func getList(lat:Double, lon:Double,handler: @escaping (Lists?,Error?)->Void) {

                Alamofire.request(ServerRequestRouter.getDataList(lat, long))
                    .responseArray(keyPath:"searchList") {(response:DataResponse<Lists>) in
                        switch response.result {
                        case .success:
                            if let data = response.result.value  {
                                handler(data, nil)
                            }
                        case .failure(let error):
                            handler(nil,error)
                        }
                }
        }
```

Error: Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter 3 cannot be represented in Objective-C.

The type which cannot be represented is the closure: `@escaping (Lists?,Error?)->Void`

How can this be changed in order to be able to call from Objective.

Note: Other calls to Swift methods from Objective-C works fine, I am just getting issues with this Swift closure operability to Objective-C.

**Edit:** Lists is a collection of a Mappable struct:

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper
import AlamofireObjectMapper

typealias Lists = [Item]

struct Item : Mappable
{
    public var id: Int!
    public var name: String!
    public var address: String!

    init?(map: Map)
    {

    }
    mutating func mapping(map: Map)
    {
        id <- map["identifier"]
        name <- map["name"]
        address <- map["address"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I get this to work. I just needed to transform my model struct into a class which inherit from NSObject and implement the `Mappable` protocol in an extension:

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper
import AlamofireObjectMapper

typealias Lists = [Item]


@objc class Item : NSObject
{
    public var id: Int!
    public var name: String!
    public var address: String!

    required init?(map: Map)
    {

    }
}
extension  Item : Mappable
{
    func mapping(map: Map)
    {
        id <- map["identifier"]
        name <- map["name"]
        address <- map["address"]
    }
}
```